# Typescript peculiarities in mapped types

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I recently stumbled upon the following snippet:

```
type NamedProperty<Name extends string, T> 
  = { [_ in 0 as Name]: T }
```

This is later used like below:

```
type TargetPropertyGroup<Name extends string> 
  = NamedProperty<`has${Capitalize<Name>}Target`, boolean> 
  & NamedProperty<`${Name}Target`, Element> 
  & NamedProperty<`${Name}Targets`, Element[]>
```

Can anybody help me figure out what `[_ in 0 as Name]` means?

I also found this bit [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggPAFShAHsCA7AJgZyj4AJwEsMBzAPigF4oBvKAbQGkpSokBDPAAwBI6zAL48AugC4oGAK4BbAEYRCUIQChVoSLAAMNWHAwQAbkqpRzFy1euWA9LaiboMXbTpqnsAIx74AIgAzPzMbULDze0dwZx83KADJGQUlAG4VDWjYACZfOEC-KAAfKD8yYPCKqEjPGBy4hKk5RUI0skSm1PSMrRgAZj0GFjYMEqCoblG-CUbk5SErasy%20gfj22bSPJYAWFaH2QIB7A4KJ-Omk5pULRZ6d%20rXmje7nAFZd1nYZABsv8bwzh5KK7XBw1N73GaPdI1ABsuwA%20sMoLpTkFzh05jYbs44RCLp01EA) but still...

Comment: to me the `in 0 as` is useless, `{[_ in Name]: T}` achieves the same here. But am I missing something ?

Comment: Here's the relevant section in the [mapped types documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) for key remapping with `as`. Is there some specific question that the documentation doesn't already answer?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler What `{[_ in Name]: T}` does even mean? 
Why can't we just do `{[Name]: T}`? Also, `in 0` should have spit out zero iterations, right?

Comment: I also noticed that rewriting this as `type NamedProperty<Name, T> = { [Name: string]: T }` doesn't work the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{ [_ in 0 as Name]: T }` means the same thing as `{ [_ in Name]: T }` as the key remapping changes nothing here.

In mapped type, the left part defines the keys, very ofter we see it as `[k in MyType]` or `[key in MyType]`. Since the key won't be reused, its replace by an underscore (like it's ofter the case in JS/TS with unused function parameters).

So `[_ in Name]` means every key in the type name. Since `Name` is just a string, the mapped type will have only one key, the string.

```
{ [_ in 0 as 'myKey']: number }  ===  { myKey: number }
```

---

In the example you give `{ [Name: string]: T }`, `Name` is not a type but a "variable". As you can see in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgWwgEwAoCcD2l2gDzxIA0UAKgHxQC8UA3lANqEQBcUAzsOgJYB2A5gF02pKAF8AUFGkzZcmQHoFUAHpUaAVV4BXdigkTQkKHGqxEKDNgi4QeAOTAIneyU48B5AwGNMvTlAARmymNPT2cHBOLmwR9uJAA), the generic parameter is unused. In mapped types, `[Name: string]` every key that is of type string.

---

About the key remapping,

Per the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as), the key remapping can be used to infer the keys from [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).